# object_getInstanceVariable works for float, int, bool, but not for double?

Tags: objective-c, return-value, objective-c-runtime

I've got `object_getInstanceVariable` to work as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217139/how-do-i-get-the-int-value-from-objectgetivarself-myintvar-as-it-returns-a-po) however it seems to only work for floats, bools and ints not doubles. I do suspect I'm doing something wrong but I've been going in circles with this.

```
float myFloatValue;
float someFloat = 2.123f;
object_getInstanceVariable(self, "someFloat", (void*)&myFloatValue);
```

works, and myFloatValue = 2.123

but when I try

```
double myDoubleValue;
double someDouble = 2.123f;
object_getInstanceVariable(self, "someDouble", (void*)&myDoubleValue);
```

I get `myDoubleValue = 0`. If I try to set `myDoubleValue` before the function eg. `double myDoubleValue = 1.2f`, the value is unchanged when I read it after the `object_getInstanceVariable` call. Setting `myIntValue` to some other value before the `getinstancevar` function above returns 2 as it should, ie. it has been changed.

then I tried

```
Ivar tmpIvar = object_getInstanceVariable(self, "someDouble", (void*)&myDoubleValue);
```

If I do `ivar_getName(tmpIvar)` I get "someDouble", but `myDoubuleValue = 0` still!  Then I try `ivar_getTypeEncoding(tmpIvar)` and I get "d" as it should be.

So to summarize, if `typeEncoding = float`, it works, if it is a double, the result is not set but it correctly reads the variable and the return value (Ivar) is also correct.

I must be doing something basic wrong that I cant see so I'd appreciate if someone could point it out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`object_getInstanceVariable` is a confused little function. It is [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getInstanceVariable) that the last parameter is a `void **` parameter—that is, you pass the address of a `void *` variable and get a pointer to the instance variable—but it is implemented as if it was a `void *` parameter—that is, you pass the address of the variable that you want to hold a copy of the instance variable. The problem is that the implementation ignores the size of the instance variable and just does a pointer copy. So anything that's the same size as a pointer will work perfectly. If you're running on a 32-bit architecture, only the high 32 bits will be copied. (You should witness the same behavior with a `long long` instance variable as well.)

The solution is to use the primary API, [key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), using `-valueForKey:`.

The other solution: If you wanted to write a fixed version, say as a category for NSObject, it would look something like this:

```
@implementation NSObject (InstanceVariableForKey)

- (void *)instanceVariableForKey:(NSString *)aKey {
    if (aKey) {
        Ivar ivar = object_getInstanceVariable(self, [aKey UTF8String], NULL);
        if (ivar) {
            return (void *)((char *)self + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

@end
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
double myDoubleValue = *(double *)[self instanceVariableForKey:@"someDouble"];
```

Comment: So thats why! I wasted an hour trying to figure out what was going on! Good explanation too.

Comment: The obj variable is never defined in the method above should actually be self, correct?

Comment: I know this is an old question. but i have just tested this and was wondering where the obj param is coming from?

Could you let me know? thanks

Comment: That would be the object whose instance variable you want to access.

Comment: I know this is very old, but how would this work with a struct? I can't seem to get it to cast correctly.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII of course it does. Doesn't `struct foo s = *(struct foo *)[self ivarForKey:@"bar"];` work?

Comment: @h2c03 I know now how to make it work. This was one of my first forays into the objective-c runtime, and I was still learning.

Answer (score 2):

What about using valueForKey:?

```
NSNumber * value = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivar_getName(tmpIvar)]];
NSLog(@"Double value: %f", [value doubleValue];
```

Note: this requires you to have a "someFloat" method.  If you want to use setValue:forKey:, you'll also need the "setSomeFloat:" method.  This is easily implemented by declaring the ivar as an @property and synthesizing it.

Comment: yup that works, didnt know about valueForKey:, though I'm still interested why the getInstanceVariable didnt work.