# Get Ivar value from CGPointin Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, runtime

Thanks for looking at my question.

I have been trying to look around and I have been playing around with low level IVars to get information from the classes. I am having trouble trying to load the values that come from CGPoint.

```
CGPoint point;   
object_getInstanceVariable(obj, [columnName UTF8String], (void **)&point);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
```

The output of this should be **{220,180}**

The i am actually getting **{220, 1.72469e-38}**

Could anyone help me out and explain why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that a CGPoint is not an object -- it's a plain-old-C struct. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are mixed up here. `point` is an instance, so `&point` is a pointer (`void *`-like), not a pointer to a pointer (`void **`-like). You need something like this:

```
CGPoint *point;   
object_getInstanceVariable(obj, [columnName UTF8String], (void **)&point);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*point));
```

Comment: CGPoint *point;
    object_getInstanceVariable(self, [@"annotationLocation" UTF8String],(void **) &point);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*point));

nice try :)

that gives me exc_bad_access

Comment: are you sure annotationLocation is a CGPoint field? Also, don't do [@"annotationLocation" UTF8String], just do "annotationLocation" without "@"

Comment: actually there are more issues with that, read better solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219081/object-getinstancevariable-works-for-float-int-bool-but-not-for-double

Comment: Thanks.... i looked at that and just tested it but was wondering where the obj param is coming from?

Could you let me know? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`object_getInstanceVariable()` only copies a pointer-worth of data at the start of the ivar's offset. That's all the storage you give it, after all, with that final `void **` argument. When you know you have more than a pointer-worth of data, as in this case, you can use `ivar_getOffset()` to find where the data starts then copy out as many bytes as you need:

```
Ivar iv = object_getInstanceVariable(obj, [columnName UTF8String], NULL);
ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(iv);
CGPoint point = *(CGPoint *)((char *)obj + offset);
```

In this case, dereferencing a `CGPoint *` causes `sizeof(CGPoint)` bytes to be copied from the referenced address; in the general case, you could `memcopy()` or `bcopy()` data from the computed address into an appropriately sized buffer.

The next problem would be computing the correct size at runtime…