# How to make a copy of a instance with objective-c runtime

Tags: objective-c, runtime

In my project there is a class which has many variables, now I want it to conform to `NSCopying` protocol, so I have to "copy" every variable in `- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone`. If the variable is a object, send copy to it, if it is a scalar value, just use assignment symbol.

The class may change frequently, which means I may add some variables afterwards, then I or somebody else may forget to modify the code in `- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone` method. To avoid it, I'm thinking about to use objective-c's runtime feature to do the work.

Below is a part of the Class, the variables in the class are ether a object or a scalar value. You will notice an array of unsigned int, it is an exception, you can omit it because I can manually copy it when the type encoding of variable is `[10I]`.

```
@interface DataObject : NSObject <NSCopying>
{
@public
    unsigned int    arrPrice[10];
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *code ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned char type ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int digit ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned int count ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned short time ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) char season ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int64_t amount ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mArray ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isOk ;

@end
```

And the `copyWithZone:`

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    DataObject *obj = [[DataObject allocWithZone:zone] init] ;
    unsigned int uVarCount = 0 ;
    Ivar *pVarList = class_copyIvarList(self.class, &uVarCount) ;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uVarCount; ++i) {
        Ivar *pVar = pVarList+i ;
        const char *name = ivar_getName(*pVar) ;
        const char *typeEncoding = ivar_getTypeEncoding(*pVar) ;
        NSString *strTypeEncoding = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:typeEncoding] ;
        if ([strTypeEncoding isEqualToString:@"[I10]"]) {
            // its arrPrice, use memcpy to copy
            memcpy(obj->arrPrice, self->arrPrice, sizeof(arrPrice)) ;
            continue ;
        } else if ([strTypeEncoding hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
            // its a object
            id o = object_getIvar(self, *pVar) ;
            o = [o copy] ;
            object_setIvar(obj, *pVar, o) ;
            NSLog(@"var name:%s, type:%s, value:%@", name, typeEncoding, o) ;
        } else {
            // runtime error
            id o = object_getIvar(self, *pVar) ;
            object_setIvar(obj, *pVar, o) ;
        }
    }
    free(pVarList) ;
    return obj ;
}
```

I get runtime error when the variable is not an object and I find [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356232/object-getivar-fails-to-read-the-value-of-bool-ivar), but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that it's hard to make a ideal solution, but my goal is to support most scalar values and objective-c object.

The main idea is to use `ivar_getOffset` to get the position of ivar and modify it directly. To achieve that I also need to know the size of the ivar, so I create a method `- (unsigned int)sizeOfTypeEncoding:(NSString *)typeEncoding supportOrNot:(BOOL *)support` which calculate the size of ivar and return it, if the type ivar is not support, `*support` would be `NO` and an Exception would be thrown.

So when I add an unsupported ivar to the class, an exception could tell me to do it manually like `arrPrice`.

```
@interface DataObject : NSObject <NSCopying>
{
@public
    unsigned int    arrPrice[10];
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *code ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned char type ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int digit ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned int count ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned short time ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) char season ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int64_t amount ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mArray ;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isOk ;

@end

@implementation DataObject

- (unsigned int)sizeOfTypeEncoding:(NSString *)typeEncoding supportOrNot:(BOOL *)support
{
    *support = YES ;
    unsigned int size = 0 ;
    if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"c"] ||
        [typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"C"]) {
        size = sizeof(char) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"i"] ||
               [typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"I"]) {
        size = sizeof(int) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"s"] ||
               [typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"S"]) {
        size = sizeof(short) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"l"] ||
               [typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"L"]) {
        size = sizeof(long) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"q"] ||
               [typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"Q"]) {
        size = sizeof(long long) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"f"]) {
        size = sizeof(float) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"d"]) {
        size = sizeof(double) ;
    } else if ([typeEncoding isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
        size = sizeof(bool) ;
    } else {
        *support = NO ;
        // v is void
        // * is char *
        // @ is object
        // # is class object
        // : is method selector
        // [ is array
        // { is struct
        // ( is union
        // b is bit
        // ^ pointer to type
        // ? other
        size = 0 ;
    }
    return size ;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    DataObject *obj = [[DataObject allocWithZone:zone] init] ;
    unsigned int uVarCount = 0 ;
    Ivar *pVarList = class_copyIvarList(self.class, &uVarCount) ;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uVarCount; ++i) {
        Ivar *pVar = pVarList+i ;
        const char *name = ivar_getName(*pVar) ;
        const char *typeEncoding = ivar_getTypeEncoding(*pVar) ;
        NSString *strTypeEncoding = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:typeEncoding] ;
        NSLog(@"var name:%s, type:%s", name, typeEncoding) ;
        if ([strTypeEncoding isEqualToString:@"[10I]"]) {
            // it is arrPrice
            memcpy(obj->arrPrice, self->arrPrice, sizeof(arrPrice)) ;
            continue ;
        }
        if ([strTypeEncoding hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
            // it is a object
            id o = object_getIvar(self, *pVar) ;
            o = [o copy] ;
            object_setIvar(obj, *pVar, o) ;
        } else {
            unsigned int size = 0 ;
            BOOL support = NO ;
            size = [self sizeOfTypeEncoding:strTypeEncoding supportOrNot:&support] ;
            if (!support) {
                NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"don't support type encoding %@", strTypeEncoding] ;
                NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"UnSupportTypeException" reason:reason userInfo:nil] ;
                [exception raise] ;
            }
            ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(*pVar) ;
            uint8_t *src = (uint8_t *)(__bridge void *)self + offset ;
            uint8_t *dst = (uint8_t *)(__bridge void *)obj + offset ;
            memcpy(dst, src, size) ;
        }
    }
    free(pVarList) ;
    return obj ;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: In OOP copying is a complex problem and generic 90 % solutions are usually no good idea. However, …

If you have a non-object reference property (`NSInteger`, `double`, `struct` and so on), you have to use `-object_getInstanceVariable ()`. But things can be more complicated.

Let's have a first try:

```
   } else {
        long *valuePointer;
        object_getInstanceVariable(self, ivar_getName(pVar), & valuePointer) ;
        object_setInstanceVariable(obj, ivar_getName(pVar), valuePointer) ;
    }
```

As you can see, I use a pointer to `long`. This is legal, if the property type is `long`. (And might be legal for every other type with the same size as `long`.) Concerning other types, especially `struct` types, you cannot do that, because they can have a different size. So to have a complete solution you have to analyze the encoding string.

At least at this point you should think again, whether a generic copy is a good idea or not. I prefer the not branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't mean to find an ideal solution and I get a solution to meet my case. By the way `object_getInstanceVariable` can't work in ARC.

Comment: Ah, yes, I remember that. Than you can read the value of the ivar via its offset (`ivar_getOffset()`).