# How to get the value from point variable of struct by Runtime method object_getIvar

Tags: ios, runtime

header:

```
@interface DisplayConnection : NSObject
{
    UIView *_view;
    struct UnityDisplaySurfaceBase *_surface;
}
@property(readonly, nonatomic) struct UnityDisplaySurfaceBase *surface;
@property(readonly, copy, nonatomic) UIView *view;
@end
```

I can get value of _view: `id value = object_getIvar(instance, _viewIvar);`
but crash when `object_getIvar(instance, _surfaceIvar)`, and can't catch exception.

help, thx.

Answer (score 1):

I just solve this.The solution works fine for C basic types/Struct.
id can't point to struct.

```
@interface DisplayConnection : NSObject
{
    UIView *_view;
    struct UnityDisplaySurfaceBase _surface;//without pointer value
}
@property(readonly, nonatomic) struct UnityDisplaySurfaceBase surface;
@property(readonly, copy, nonatomic) UIView *view;
@end
@implementation DisplayConnection 
- (UnityDisplaySurfaceBase)someValue {



Ivar inner = class_getInstanceVariable ([self class], "_surface");
ptrdiff_t offset = ivar_getOffset(inner);
unsigned char *stuffBytes = (unsigned char *)(__bridge void *)self;
UnityDisplaySurfaceBase someVar = * ((UnityDisplaySurfaceBase *)(stuffBytes + offset));

return  someVar;
}
@end
```

refer to:[https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356232/object-getivar-fails-to-read-the-value-of-bool-ivar)
refer to:[https://www.bignerdranch.com](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/inside-the-bracket-part-5-runtime-api/)